# Телеграм-бот telegraf.js не работает на другом пк и на мобильном

Tags: javascript, node.js, frontend, telegraf

Всем привет, делаю бота на JavaScript, задача получить у пользователя аудиофайл и описание к нему, конвертировать полученный аудиофайл в голосовое сообщение и вернуть пользователю это сообщение вместе с описанием.

В текущий момент при использовании бота с моего пк все работает как надо, но при добавлении файла с другого пк или с телефона, ничего не происходит, бот не выдает оповещений и не конвертирует полученный файл. Не могу понять в чем причина. Документация у библиотеки не очень и в сети информации не нашел. Буду благодарен за ответ.

В текущий момент код бота выглядит так:

```html
bot.on("message", async (ctx) => {
  if (ctx.message.document !== undefined) {
      const audio = ctx.message.document;
      const { file_name } = audio;
      const fileId = audio.file_id;
      const filePath = await bot.telegram.getFileLink(fileId);
      const fileStream = createWriteStream(
        `./audio/${file_name.split('.')[0]}.${audio.mime_type.split("/")[1]}`
      );
      await new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        https
          .get(filePath.href, (response) => {
            response.pipe(fileStream);
            fileStream.on("finish", resolve);
          })
          .on("error", (err) => {
            // console.error(err);
            fileStream.unlink();
            reject(err);
          });
      });

      console.log(fileStream);

      if (ctx.message.caption) {
        userDescription = ctx.message.caption;
      }
      const voiceMessage = await ctx.telegram.sendVoice(ctx.chat.id, {
        source: `./audio/${file_name.split(".")[0]}.${
          audio.mime_type.split("/")[1]
        }`,
        reply: ctx.reply(
          `Вы прислали аудиофайл "${file_name}" и добавили к нему следующее описание:  ${userDescription}. 
           Ожидайте, файл конвертируется...`,
          Extra.Markup.forceReply(ctx.message.message_id)
        ),
      });
  } else {
    userDescription = ctx.message.text;
  }
  
});

bot.launch();

process.once("SIGINT", () => bot.stop("SIGINT"));
process.once("SIGTERM", () => bot.stop("SIGTERM"));
```